# WPF displaying Session username in a text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cmd

I am working on a project using WPF where I have to display the computer's username as a text string in WPF.

I know we use **%username%** cmd command to retrieve the session username however how to use it in as a string in a WPF application?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to install System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement NuGet Package.

Then you have declare a string in your **.cs** file:

```
private string UsernameText = Environment.Username;
public string UsernameText
{
   get => UsernameText;
   set 
   {
      if (UsernameText != value)
      {
         UsernameText = value;
      }
   }
}
```

and in your **.xaml** file:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SessionUsernameText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Alternatively you can install System.Security.Principal.Windows NuGet package and use: **private string SessionUsernameText = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1]);**